# How can I reference annotation arguments in a custom Spring annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-annotations

I have an `abstract` `class` with methods requiring certain permissions. I would like the implementing classes to be able to require additional permissions, while still requiring those from the abstract class. Simply adding another `@PreAuthorize` annotation seems to override whatever was required in the abstract class, so my idea was to implement an annotation of my own.

My question is: how do I reference arguments in the `@PreAuthorize` annotation?

This code:

```
// Custom annotation
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('BASE_PERMISSION') and hasRole('#role')")
public @interface MyCustomPreAuthorize {
    String role() default "";
}

// Implementing class
@MyCustomPreAuthorize(role = "ANOTHER_ROLE")
```

does not seem to work.